# Retrieving the current step with BS-stepper

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-5

Any idea how can I get the current page with the [bs-stepper](https://github.com/Johann-S/bs-stepper)? I've been trying to deal with that for like an hour now.

The code now:

```
<script>
    var stepper = new Stepper($('.bs-stepper')[0]);
</script>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Listen for event `'shown.bs-stepper'` then store the `event.detailindexStep` in the element's .data so you can read it whenever you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stepper instance has a "private" but accessible property `_currentIndex`. See this pen: https://codepen.io/Hazzamanic/pen/KKvJqKR or the code below

You can also listen for a step change:

```
var stepperElement = document.getElementById('stepper');
var stepper = new Stepper(stepperElement);
// get current index from stepper
var currentIndex = stepper._currentIndex;

stepperElement.addEventListener('shown.bs-stepper', function (event) {
  console.log('Moved to step ' + event.detail.indexStep)
})
```

Please note that the event is added to the **element**, not the instance of Stepper. Also, if you are using jquery, you will need to bind the event using `.on()` or retrieve the underlying dom element like so:

```
$("#stepper")[0].addEventListener('shown.bs-stepper', function (event) {
  console.log('Moved to step ' + event.detail.indexStep)
})
```

Comment: And how am I supposed to reach it?

Comment: Here is a pen: https://codepen.io/Hazzamanic/pen/KKvJqKR?editors=1111

Comment: Okay, this pen is working right. How do I call a onchange event for the **stepper._currentIndex**?

Comment: Have updated my answer, you can listen for the steps changing

Comment: I need to hide/show elements based on current step. Saw you edit. I guess its going to happen with `if(event.details.indexStep == NUMBER) { do smth}` ?

Comment: Yes that would work. Please note it is `event.detail.indexStep`, no `s` on detail :)

Comment: **stepper2.addEventListener is not a function** - getting this error.. (2 is the stepper identificator - there are multiple steppers in multiple modals for multiple divs so i gave every stepper an identification number so each div is having a separate modal with stepper).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239355/discussion-between-keneferinho95-and-hazza).

Comment: Any idea how do I stop the (next) button from going to next step in the listener?

Comment: There are two events you can listen to, `show.bs-stepper` and `shown.bs-stepper`. If you listen for the `show.bs-stepper` event, it is called before moving the stepper so you can call `event.preventDefault()` in the handler to stop the stepper moving forward

Comment: Okay, **event.preventDefault()** is working fine, but how do I allow the stepper to move forward after that? Because once **event.preventDefault()** is executed it wont let it continue..

Comment: I think this needs a new question as I'm not sure what the context is now

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<script>
var stepper = new Stepper($('.bs-stepper')[0]);
let curPage = stepper._currentIndex;
</script>
```

Comment: Thats working! How do I call a onchange event for the **stepper._currentIndex**?